# How to simulate command+q as a tmux prefix in iTerm2?

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> as tmux's prefix key in my Linux server.

Now I connect my Linux server on my MacBook in iTerm2.
I want to map <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> in iTerm2.

So I config keys tab in iTerm2 preferences and add key bindings <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to trigger send a *hex* code. I try sending hex code `0x11` (ctrl) `0x47` (q), but it is not work.

Why?